# How to force an accordion's view at the top of its section

Tags: jquery

I've got a page with long accordion sections in it. The first one opens fine, when you click on the second one it scrolls down to the bottom of that section. The user would then have to scroll back up-a very bad user experience! Is it possible to click and have them open at the top of the section? I've looked around quite a bit but jquery is not my strong suit!

```
<div class="accordion">
        <div style="padding-top: 20%" class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title">Title</a>
            <img class="top-image" style="margin:0px auto;display:block" src="images/flip-flips-shoes.jpg"/>
            <p class="top-p">A little text about project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <a class="accordion-section-title fa fa-arrow-circle-down greytext" href="#accordion-1"></a>

            <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
                <div class="border"></div>
                <div class="work-left">
                    <h4>Project Title</h4>
                    <p>Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. </p>
                </div>

            </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="accordion-section grey">
        <a class="accordion-section-title top">Title</a>
        <img class="top-image" style="margin:0px auto;display:block" src="images/flip-flips-shoes.jpg"/>
        <p class="top-p">A little text about project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <a class="accordion-section-title fa fa-arrow-circle-down" href="#accordion-2"></a>

            <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
                <div class="border-white"></div>
                <div class="work-left">
                    <h4>Project Title</h4>
                    <p>Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Text explaining the project goes here. Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. </p>
                </div>           
    </div> 
  </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
function close_accordion_section() {
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}

$('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
        close_accordion_section();
    }else {
        close_accordion_section();

        // Add active class to section title
        $(this).addClass('active');
        // Open up the hidden content panel
        $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Comment: Your problm is not clear. Can u recreate your issue in https://jsfiddle.net/